# colcon build error: can't copy 'resource/<pkg-name>': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS2 Humble in Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS.

This is very surprising to me. Until yesterday the [package](https://github.com/tsadarsh/beaming) (beaming: I am making this package for my robot) was building fine. But today when I tried doing a `colcon build` it fails with the following error:

```
Starting >>> beaming 
 stderr: beaming                   
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
error: can't copy 'resource/beaming': doesn't exist or not a regular file
Failed   <<< beaming [1.37s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [2.06s]
  1 package failed: beaming
  1 package had stderr output: beaming
```

I made sure that I was sourcing the workspace before doing the `colcon build`.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072031/ros2-colcon-build-fails-cant-copy-doesnt-exist-or-not-a-regular-file) issue similar to mine but the same error shows up even after deleting `build/` and `install/` directories as proposed in the solutions.
Is this is an issue with the *colcon* tool or something local in my workspace? How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411003/colcon-build-error:-can%27t-copy-%27resource/%3Cpkg-name%3E%27:-doesn%27t-exist-or-not-a-regular-file/) by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2023-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem. It was pretty trivial and silly.

All I had to do was make a directory `resource/` in the place where `setup.py` and `package.xml` exists and create an empty file inside the `resource/` directory with the name same as the **package** name.

I might have not included this directory when I did a `git add`. Hence, when I cloned this package I faced this error. I would still like to know the purpose of the `resource/` directory.

---

Originally posted by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) with karma: 78 on 2023-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bribri123](https://answers.ros.org/users/78090/bribri123/) on 2023-03-04**:
my resource folder was already there i just needed to rename the file inside